# Comparing Strings in As3

Tags: string, actionscript-3, if-statement

I'm currently coding a game for an assignment and I need help comparing Strings. 
The question in the game asks the users to type out a specific sequence on their keyboard. I have provided a sequence "SWAGAFFAD" and I want my code to compare a the values that people might enter. If they get the sequence correct I want them to be able to proceed to the next question and if they don't type in the exact sequence they just get an error message come up. Just not sure how to code this. Can someone help me out? Assuming I'd need an IF  ELSE statement?? 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could you edit your question and add what you have tried so far, or a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `if ("SWAGAFFAD" == enteredStrings){
 // Do something
}
else{
 // error
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use the == and != operators to compare strings with each other and to compare strings with other types of objects, as the following example shows:

```
var str1:String = "1"; 
var str1b:String = "1"; 
var str2:String = "2"; 
trace(str1 == str1b); // true 
trace(str1 == str2); // false 
var total:uint = 1; 
trace(str1 == total); // true
```

for more detail info [adobe doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eef.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectUtil.compare(string1,string2)`. It will return 0 if both the strings are equal else 1 or -1

Answer (score 0):

Yes you might want to use if-else statement and == operator as others suggested. Here's one very simple way:

```
var word:String = "SWAGAFFAD";
var index:int = 0;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);

function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == word.split("")[index]){
        index++;
        trace("Correct letter!");
        if(index == word.length){
            //Player got the whole word, proceed to next one
        }
    }else{
        //Wrong letter, do something else
    }
}
```